# ASP.NET MVC Git Pull does not work for me

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, git

I want to pull latest push from git repo with c# subprocess.
What I tryed is:

It get lates push from my repo,notpulling new changes from remote repo, What I did wrong("fetch and pull is not working but reset hard is working")

```
            Process process = new Process();
            process = GetProcess("reset --hard");
            process.Start();               
            process.WaitForExit();

            process = GetProcess("fetch origin");
            process.Start(); 
            while (process.StandardOutput.Peek() >= 0)
            {
                ViewBag.text+= process.StandardOutput.ReadLine();
            }
            process.WaitForExit();

            process = GetProcess("checkout -B \"" + branchname + "\" 
             \"origin/" + branchname + "\" ");
            process.Start();
            while (process.StandardOutput.Peek() >= 0)
            {
                ViewBag.text+= process.StandardOutput.ReadLine();
            }

            process.WaitForExit();
            process = GetProcess("pull --progress origin");
            process.Start();
            while (process.StandardOutput.Peek() >= 0)
            {
                ViewBag.text+= process.StandardOutput.ReadLine();
            }
            process.WaitForExit();

 public Process GetProcess(string arg)
    {
        ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("git.exe");
        startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        startInfo.WorkingDirectory = projectPath;
        startInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

        Process process = new Process();
        process.StartInfo = startInfo;

        startInfo.Arguments = arg;
        return process;
    }
```

Comment: Fetch says "Logon failed, use ctrl+c to cancel basic credential prompt." StandardErorOutput

Comment: error: could not lock config file C:/WINDOWS/system32/config/systemprofile/.gitconfig: Permission denied

Comment: Anyone to fix this?